# Ruby CSV doesn't find file headers if first line is followed by an empty one

Tags: ruby, csv

I have encountered an odd issue where my script wouldn't work on some CSV files. Problem is the following, I need to access the column names (file headers) to properly process the file. I've been using the following (test) code to list the headers :

```
CSV file = CSV.read(argument, :headers => true)
if file.headers() == nil
    puts "According to the doc : Headers will not be used"
elsif file.headers() == true
    puts "According to the doc : Headers will be used, but not read yet"
else
    puts "Headers were read, this is an array : #{file.headers.to_s}"
end
```

Now, applied to the first csv :

```
key,fr
edit,Éditer
close,Fermer
```

I get :

```
Headers were read, this is an array : ["key", "fr"]
```

But, if I know add an empty line between the headers and the content itself, like so :

```
key,fr

edit,Éditer
close,Fermer
```

It doesn't work anymore :

```
Headers were read, this is an array : []
```

This baffles me. Is this expected behavior ? Is there anything I can do about it ? I've been reading the ruby CSV doc but cannot find anything.
Could it be some csv file specs I don't know about ?
Tested on ruby 1.9.3 and 2.1.1

Comment: what are you expecting ? If you get such a file, it is not a valid CSV file.

Comment: If the file you read stems from user input you could try to anticipate simple errors like this by rejecting empty lines before passing it to CSV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the option `:skip_blanks => true` when you are reading the **CSV** file.

```
file = CSV.read(path, :headers => true,:skip_blanks => true)
```

This option `:skip_blanks => true`, will skip all such blank lines if any present like you are having, and you will get the normal output.

Here is my try for the same :

```
require 'csv'

content = <<_
key,fr

edit,Éditer
close,Fermer
_

File.write('test',content)

file = CSV.read('test', :headers => true,:skip_blanks => true)
if file.headers() == nil
    puts "According to the doc : Headers will not be used"
elsif file.headers() == true
    puts "According to the doc : Headers will be used, but not read yet"
else
    puts "Headers were read, this is an array : #{file.headers.to_s}"
end
# >> Headers were read, this is an array : ["key", "fr"]
```

Working correctly as you said, and I also agreed with you, below one :

```
require 'csv'

content = <<_
key,fr
edit,Éditer
close,Fermer
_

File.write('test',content)

file = CSV.read('test', :headers => true)
file.headers # => ["key", "fr"]
file.to_a # => [["key", "fr"], ["edit", "Éditer"], ["close", "Fermer"]]
```

When you set `:headers => true`, the first row of the CSV data, you have will be tread as **header**. With this definition in mind, The above goes well. But the below one contradicts :

```
require 'csv'

File.write('test',content)

file = CSV.read('test', :headers => true)
file.headers # => ["key", "fr"]
file.to_a # => [["key", "fr"], ["edit", "Éditer"], ["close", "Fermer"]]

content = <<_
key,fr

edit,Éditer
close,Fermer
_

File.write('test1',content)

file = CSV.read('test1', :headers => true)
file.headers # => []  # <~~~~~~~~~~~ Is this a bug ?
file.to_a # => [[], [], ["edit", "Éditer"], ["close", "Fermer"]]
```

`file.headers` gives an empty array `[]`, as you can see that in the **0<sup>th</sup>** index of the output of `file.to_a` is also an empty array(`[]`). But it seems to a bug. Thus I raised the [*issue*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9582).