# How to get headers from a CSV.read on a CSV file with only a header row in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

So, I've been messing around with CSV files in Ruby, and I've come across an issue. In my testing, a call of x = CSV.read(file, headers:true) on a file which only contains the header row will return a table, that, when converted to an array, returns [[]], and calling x.headers returns []. I can circumvent this problem by setting return_headers:true, but I don't actually want the file to return its headers, I just want the headers. When I add in a fake, second row, x.headers actually returns the headers, and :return_headers does not need to be set to true.

Here is some code from before and after adding a row to help visualize the issue.

With headers:true, return_headers:true on a csv file with only the header row:

```
a = CSV.read("June.csv", headers:true, return_headers:true) # <CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:1>
a[0] # <CSV::Row "Day":"Day" "Time":"Time">
a.headers # => ["Day", "Time"]
```

With only headers:true on a csv file with only the header row:

```
b = CSV.read("June.csv", headers:true) #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:1>
b[0] # => nil
b.headers # => []
```

With only headers:true on a csv file with the fake second row:

```
c = CSV.read("June.csv", headers:true) #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:2>
c.headers # => ["Day", "Time"]
c["Day"] # => ["6/1"]
```

I can't depend on the CSV file I have to always have a second row, because my program intends to build on it. What am I doing wrong? Is this the intended behavior, or is the problem in my setup, somehow? Do I have to do a read just for the headers, and then another read to get the behavior I would like? I've searched for a good while, but am still having trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing is expected. A somewhat similar question two years ago had an [answer that pointed out the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22102521/1241782) you're having. That person opened a [bug report for Ruby](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9582) where the Ruby devs responded and rejected it. And according to some people that is technically not a well-formed CSV.

However, I agree with you and the person who opened the bug. The `headers: true` option should fill out the `CSV.headers` regardless of whether there is actually data on the following lines or not. The current behavior seems baffling and will only lead to bugs in code.

As a quick fix for your issue I would simply pass `return_headers: true` and begrudgingly skip over the first entry in the result, which will always be the header row.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I had no idea this was a thing and I'm sorry that I hadn't found that bug report on my own. I try to solve my problems myself before I run anything by stack, but I guess this is just one I'll have to live with. Thanks again!!!